# spider : importError: DLL load failed: Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service

Tags: python, web-crawler, anaconda

while performing import "from sklearn.cluster import KMeans" in spider ,i am getting the error mentioned below:
importError: DLL load failed: Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstall:

```
pip uninstall sklearn

Then delete manually old the folders of sklearn from all installations of Python

(Anaconda : /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages and /Library/Python/2.7)

pip install -U scikit-learn
```

[Reference](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3048).